# remove mouseenter function jquery on when window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different functions that I trigger depending on screen size. The desktop function means that when you hover/mouseenter over an element an animation occurs.

On mobile the animation occurs when you click on the element. The issue is when i resize from a desktop to a mobile the hover/mouseenter effect is still attached. Does anyone know how I can remove the hover/mouseenter when the screen is resized.

Currently my code looks like the below.

```
var isMobile = isMob();

function isMob() {
    if($(window).width() > 1000) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.hover-zone').css('display', 'block');
    isMobile = isMob();
    if(isMobile){
        mobileAnimate(); 
    }  
    if(!isMobile){  
        deskTopAnimate();
    }
});

if(isMobile){
    mobileAnimate(); 
}

if(!isMobile){  
    deskTopAnimate();
}

function deskTopAnimate() {
    $('.hover-zone').mouseenter(function(){
        desktopAnimateOut.play();
    });

    $('.desktop-close').click(function(){
        desktopAnimateOut.reverse();
    })
}

function mobileAnimate() {
    //current attempt to prevent
    $('.hover-zone').mouseenter(function(){
        return;
    })
    $('.hover-zone').click(function(){
        animateOut.play();
    });

    $('.mobile-close').click(function(){
        animateOut.reverse();
    })
}
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's [off method](http://api.jquery.com/off/). Change `.mouseenter(` to `.on('mouseenter'`

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks man!

Comment: @evolutionxbox You are correct, although the change you suggested isn't necessary. `.off()` works with `.mouseenter()`, `.click()`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the mobile part with that;

```
function mobileAnimate() {
    //current attempt to prevent
    $('.hover-zone').off('mouseenter'); // removes the bind
    $('.hover-zone').click(function(){
        animateOut.play();
    });

    $('.mobile-close').click(function(){
        animateOut.reverse();
    })
}
```

If that doesn't work try that one;

```
$(document).off('mouseenter','.hover-zone');
```